# Can I modify the perforce credential with jenkins groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, perforce

I am using the newer "p4" [perforce plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/P4+Plugin) and I have a couple dozen jobs.  I need to now change the Perforce credentials.  The following groovy script (run in Script Console) will print them out, but the "credential" field in [PerforceScm.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/p4-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/p4/PerforceScm.java) is final so I can't modify it.  Is there a way to update this configuration?

```
projects = Hudson.instance.projects
projects.each(proj ->
    println(scm.credential)
}
```

I feel there must be some configuration item used to construct a PerforceScm object.  E.g. there is a descriptor, available using "scm.getDescriptor()", that has a credential field.  But that field is null when I print it.

Comment: I avoid using p4 plugin..we can export the required credential in the execute shell of build step..(like ..export P4PORT=somevalue), likewise for P4USER, P4CLIENT ..etc..there might be a configuration in groovy script to get hold of shell of build step in Hudson..there you can export these values

Answer (score 1):

If you loop over the Hudson.instance.items you can use item.scm.setP4Passwd("") to update the value.

Example

```
for(item in Hudson.instance.items) {
  if(item.scm instanceof hudson.plugins.perforce.PerforceSMC) {
    item.scm.setP4Passwd("asdf");
    item.save();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def jenkins = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
def srcJob = jenkins.getItemByFullName(<SOURCE_JOB>)
scm = srcJob.scm;
if(scm instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM){
   print "need to check for git or simply ignore."
}else if(scm instanceof hudson.plugins.perforce.PerforceSCM){
   scm.setP4Passwd("*******")
   scm.setP4User("newUser")
}
```